# Casting of struct to specific address of byte slice

Tags: pointers, go, struct, casting, slice

To parse a huge file without having to copy bytes for every struct, I would like to cast structs directly to an address in a byte slice. This is solely for performance reasons.
I am aware that I can use binary.Read() to make a struct from a byte slice, but as I understand this will copy the bytes, which is a costly affair; hence I would like to avoid using this approach in this use case.

I do seem to have casted the struct, since I do get the data in the struct that I expect. However, when I change values in my struct they do not change the byte slice that the struct address should point to? It is important for me that the file (byte slice) reflects the change of data in my struct.

How can I have the struct working on the corresponding address in the file?

This is a demo of what I have done this far:

```
type T struct {
    A uint8
}

func main() {

    data := []byte{0xA, 0xB, 0xC}

    // Cast bytes to struct
    pointer := *(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
    fmt.Printf("ptr:\t0x%x\n", pointer)

    t2 := *(*T)(unsafe.Pointer(&pointer))
    fmt.Printf("T:\t0x%x\n\n", t2.A)
    // byte casting to struct ends here

    // test
    t2.A = 0x0 // I expect this to change for data as well but it does not.

    fmt.Println("AFTER CHANGE OF t2.A")
    fmt.Printf("data[0]:0x%x\n", data[0])
    fmt.Printf("ptr:\t0x%x\n\n", pointer)

    fmt.Println("WHY ARE THESE ON DIFFERENT ADDRESSES?")
    fmt.Printf("DataAddr: 0x%p\n", data)
    fmt.Printf("PtrAddr: 0x%p\n", &pointer)
    fmt.Printf("T2Addr: 0x%p\n", &t2)

}
```

This prints out:

```
ptr:    0xa
T:      0xa

AFTER CHANGE OF t2.A - the original data slice has not been altered.
data[0]:0xa
ptr:    0xa

ADDRESSES
DataAddr: 0x0xc000094010
PtrAddr: 0x0xc000094013
T2Addr: 0x0xc000094030
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You properly convert the pointer, but then you derefernce it, which makes a copy. Then you go on and take the address of the copy, convert that pointer and you dereference it again (which makes another copy). Modifying any of the copies will not have any effect on other copies.

So simply do not dereference the pointers (and ultimately we just modify the *pointed* values which will be at the same memory location):

```
data := []byte{0xA, 0xB, 0xC}

// Cast bytes to struct
pointer := (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
fmt.Printf("ptr:\t0x%x\n", *pointer)

t2 := (*T)(unsafe.Pointer(pointer))
fmt.Printf("T:\t0x%x\n\n", t2.A)
// byte casting to struct ends here

// test
t2.A = 0x0 // This will also change data

fmt.Println("AFTER CHANGE OF t2.A")
fmt.Printf("data[0]:0x%x\n", data[0])
fmt.Printf("ptr:\t0x%x\n\n", *pointer)

fmt.Println("ADDRESSES ARE ALL THE SAME:")
fmt.Printf("DataAddr: 0x%p\n", &data[0])
fmt.Printf("PtrAddr: 0x%p\n", pointer)
fmt.Printf("T2Addr: 0x%p\n", t2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BHjGFZT9Um5)):

```
ptr:    0xa
T:  0xa

AFTER CHANGE OF t2.A
data[0]:0x0
ptr:    0x0

ADDRESSES ARE ALL THE SAME:
DataAddr: 0x0x40e020
PtrAddr: 0x0x40e020
T2Addr: 0x0x40e020
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift reply. Your answer is much appreciated!